# Selecting all files in directory for merging in QGIS Processing?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm writing a generic script which involves writing shapefiles to a directory which are then merged together. After writing the files out to the *Output* folder, I'm trying to get the **saga:mergeshapeslayers** algorithm to merge all the files in the *Output* folder. I have used the Model Builder and although it is helpful to an extent, I find that it is used for specific purposes whereas I am attempting to make a script for generic purposes.

Code:

```
##Test=name
##Select_folder=folder
##Result=output vector

import os
import glob

path_1 = Select_folder
path = path_1
os.chdir(path)

def function():

    output = glob.glob(path_1 + './*.shp')
    x = 0

    while output[x]:
        for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
            outputs_1 = processing.runandload("qgis:fieldcalculator", output[x], 'Number', 1, 10, 0, True, 1 , "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Output\\"  + fname)
            multiple_0 = glob.glob("*.shp")
            x = x + 1

        if x + 1 > len(output):
            processing.runalg("saga:mergeshapeslayers", output[0], ";".join(multiple_0) , Result)
            break
        else:
            continue

if path_1:
    function()
else:
   pass
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you are trying to do. What is `Z`?. What does the `function(Z)` serve if it returns nothing ? What is the difference between `glob.glob(Z + './*.shp')`and `glob.glob("*.shp")`?

Comment: Thanks @gene and apologies, edited the code so that it hopefully looks better. To my limited understanding, the difference is that `glob.glob(path_1 + './*.shp')` defines where the .shp files are; and `glob.glob("*.shp")` fetches the filenames of the .shp files. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: To try to be more clear as to what I want: I can write the shapefiles from a given folder into "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Output\\". I would then like the **saga:mergeshapeslayers** to merge all files in that Output folder. The code for the merge algorithm is incorrect and would like to know any solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your script without using `while...` and `x`, `x+1`: for simple Python list, it would be best to use `for` or [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
##Test=name
##Select_folder=folder
##Result=output vector

import os
import glob
# folder path of Result shapefile
path_res = os.path.dirname(Result)
# go to Select_folder
os.chdir(Select_folder)
# copy the shapefiles (you don't need to load the shapefiles, so use runalg)
for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
     outputs_1 = processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", fname, 'Number', 1, 10, 0, True, 1 , path_res  + "/"+ fname) 

# paths of the shapefiles in the Result folder with list comprehension
output = [path_res + "/"+ shp for shp in glob.glob("*.shp")]
# merge the shapefiles
processing.runalg("saga:mergeshapeslayers", output[0], ";".join(output) , Result)
```

Some explications:

```
#  folder path of the Result shapefile # = path_res
print  os.path.dirname("/Users/Shared/test.shp")
/Users/Shared

# list comprehension
print [shp for shp in glob.glob("*.shp")]
['shape1.shp', 'shape2.shp',..., 'shapen.shp']
print [path_res + "/"+ shp for shp in glob.glob("*.shp")]
['/Users/Shared/shape1.shp', '/Users/Shared/shape2.shp', ...,'/Users/Shared/shapen.shp']
```

or better with `os.path.join` (universal, Windows, Linux, Mac OS X):

```
print [os.path.join(path_res, shp) for shp in glob.glob("*.shp")]
print [os.path.join(path_res, shp) for shp in glob.glob("*.shp")][0] # = output[0]
/Users/Shared/shape1.shp
```

Comment: Very clear, concise and incredibly helpful. Thank you very much! One question: Isn't line 3 supposed to be `##Result=output vector`?

Comment: yes and thanks, corrected, but it is your idea (adapted by me)

Comment: Your adaption has definitely taught me, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer thanks to @gene who's comments helped me focus on the right area. Just had to simply to use glob for the **saga:mergeshapeslayers** function to call:

```
multiple_0=glob.glob("*.shp")
```

Added this to the code above which now merges all files in the folder.

Comment: can you correct the indentation of your script, please. As proposed, it does not work.

Comment: ok but you can simplify your script (see below)

Comment: Just in case someone runs into the same problem as I did.
saga:mergeshapeslayers wasn't found, but saga:mergelayers does the same thing. This was on 2.12.1 (OS X 10.11.3).

Comment: @cmyk - Thanks buddy, I didn't mention in the post but it was an old version of QGIS and the _Processing_ plugin (I think v2.2 for both).